# Qt: QTableWidget/QTableView alternating row colors in full viewport

Tags: qt, user-interface

I have a QTableView containing data rows from a database. However, setting setAlternatingRowColors(true) only alternates row colors that has data - the rest of the table is just white, which is not the behaviour you'd expect (look in the bookmark list of any browser, for example - empty rows has alternating colors).

Does anyone know a workarund or an alternative to the table views supplied by Qt? I've fiddled with stylesheets and item delegates, same result.

Comment: Did you find anything yourself? I have the same problem.

Comment: I ended up using a QTreeView / QTreeWidget instead. It's easy making them behave like tables. However, obviously a QTable* and a QTree* should behave in the same way in regards to filling out empty rows with alternating colors, but...

Answer (score 12):

Why don't you use Qt QSS for this? It working just fine. Have a look here : http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/42211-QTableWidget-alternating-background-color?p=263046#post263046

```
myTable->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
myTable->setStyleSheet("alternate-background-color: yellow;background-color: red;");
```

Comment: alternating color is simple, but making the alternating color fill the entire rows when the data is not enough, is different matter

Answer (score 5):

You could reimplement `data()` method of your model like this:

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    if(role == Qt::BackgroundColorRole)
        return color;
    ...
}
```

It should be possible to do the same with a delegate using `setModelData()`.

Comment: Should. In my case it works. You can try it will not take much time.

Answer (score 0):

As an workaround, fill the rest of the table with void rows (i.e. in the model, rowCount() override to give enough empty rows to fill it.)