# In QTableView/QTableWidget : How to make the alternating rows to fully vertically fill the table?

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtablewidget

Have a look at below image, which is a QTableWidget :

[image]

You can see that it's a rows with alternating color.  But you can also see that it's not vertically filled the table. Which gives a --in my perspective-- rather unpleasant appearance.

If the row content is unable to fill the table vertically, how can we make sure that the alternating rows get drawn vertically full?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452207/qt-qtablewidget-qtableview-alternating-row-colors-in-full-viewport, where the OP did not find an answer, but ended up using a QTreeView/QTreeWidget to get the desired effect.

Comment: I have already see that thread! Hm.. I think that last answer is good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's IMHO not possible without subclassing QTableWidget since Qt only colors actual table rows. In your example the table is not entirely filled with rows, so there's no alternating coloring of the whole table.

Comment: I indeed subclass the above QTableWidget.. do you think there is no other way than to fake an empty rows when the data is not enough to fill the table?

Comment: I also have trouble in trying to fit the row height to its contents. Now the problem is still there, but it's not that bad either. :)